# Unable to access data annotation from partial class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Using ASP.NET MVC pattern I have an Entity Framework stored in the `Models->Northwind` which includes `Region.cs` class. I also have a `Partial` Folder which contains `RegionalPartial.cs` which includes Data annotation for `region.cs`

Here is the Directory structure

[image]

The `Region.cs` looks like :

```
namespace Map.Models.Northwind
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Region
    {
        public int RegionID { get; set; }

        public string RegionDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the `RegionPartial.cs` is like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Map.Models.Northwind.Partials
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    [MetadataType(typeof(RegionMetaData))]
    public partial class Region {}

    public class RegionMetaData
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "REGION DESCRIPTION")]
        public object RegionDescription { get; set; }

    }
}
```

but the `Region.cs` is not using the data annotation stored in the `RegionPartial.cs`! Why is this happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks like two different Region types - one in each namespace.  Drop the .Partials and see if it compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the namespace in `RegionPartial.cs` from

```
Map.Models.Northwind.Partials
```

to

```
Map.Models.Northwind
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul but why this was happening?

Comment: regarding to this tutorial https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation "Notice that each class is marked as a partial class, and each matches the name and namespace as the class that is automatically generated"